# Nvidia-settings PowerMizer performance-mode on 12.04.4 64-bit

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, performance, lts

Whenever I try to set the performance mode of my Nvidia 525M gpu from adaptive to performance, it actually works, but only until I reboot my PC. After a reboot/relog I have to do it all over again via nvidia-settings.

- What is the official/safest way to make that change permanent?
- Why doesn't nvidia-settings save the performance mode it has been set to? Is it a bug?

I am using the official Nvidia 331 drivers provided by Ubuntu 12.04.4 64-bit LTS.

Thanks!

Comment: Does the info in the link also work for Ubuntu 12.04.4 64-bit? The user in the link is using Ubuntu 12.10. I just want to be sure before I change something so important, especially if it requires editing/hacking xorg.conf etc.

Comment: Yes, it works for any Linux distro that uses a Proprietary Nvidia driver. It's not a big deal, and you'll probably need to create xorg.conf, cause it's not there by default.

Comment: Hello Mike, thanks for the answer. Are you 100% sure of this? I ask because I have seen reports about it causing boot issues etc. According to another user, the code is different for each gpu. See here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/172806/nvidia-powermizer-performance-levels?rq=1

Comment: Well, I've tested mine, and know that it worked, ...for me. I haven't seen reports of boot problems, anyway, in case you have any, the change is easily reversible.

Comment: Hello friend, thx for the help you gave me. I decided to ask Nvidia directly about this, just to be sure. Below is the official answer/workaround for this issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Solution for my GPU question:** I contacted Nvidia directly via [live-chat](http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/chat/chat_launch/session/L3RpbWUvMTM5MjEwOTU2Mi9zaWQvbUt5X0VFTWw=), because I wanted to know how to fix the issue above in the most safest and easy way. There are a lot of old guides on the net. Some work, some don't work. I need the risk to be minimal, since I am on a stable LTS machine here.

**This is the workaround Nvidia provided me for Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS 64-bit:**

> It is expected that powermizer settings are not saved after reboot.
>
> As a workaround, you can set "prefer maximum performance" on the
>   command line with `nvidia-settings -a [gpu:0]/GpuPowerMizerMode=1`.
>   Replace gpu:0 with gpu:N if there is more than one GPU.
>
> You can place that nvidia-settings invocation in ~/.xinitrc or some
>   other startup script. (It must be done after X is started)

I recommend doing it via the "start-up programs" utility, because it's relatively easy and because it ships with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Copy and paste the command into it, save and it will load on the next restart.

**Screenshots**

**1.** Open the start-up program utility and add the recommended command and a comment into it:
[image: First step]

**2.** Activate it afterwards:
[image: Second step]

**3.** Restart your computer and check PowerMizer via nvidia-settings:
[image: Third step]

Done. Maximum power! Btw, this also helps if Unity is running slow or if you have any form stuttering, tearing, slowdown or lag in apps when PowerMizer switched from a low to a high performance-level. Credit goes to Mike from Nvidia customer care. He responded to me within 24 hours after asking my question, which is great. I am posting this information to let other Ubuntu users know how the issue was fixed. Thanks!

**Update for Maxwell GTX 900-series GPUs**: See [This spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0Ak6s-8up66hRdEw5RkxVcDhwM0xiU0dUaDZBU1ptdkE&output=html). It details setting up overclocking. Search for Nvidia to get the necessary details.  This was tested on a GTX 970 on Kubuntu 14.10.

Comment: it works perfectly.this eliminates  randomn lags in desktop effects in linux mint 18.1.it should also  help in gaming.but i only recommend this for desktop.downside is high power consumption and heat.thank you aquablue.