# Slow window switching in 15.04

Tags: unity, drivers, nvidia, graphics, 15.04

Upon upgrade to Ubuntu 15.04, my window switching (alt+tab, super+w) suddenly became laggy. I thought maybe something went wrong in the upgrade so I did a fresh install just to be sure. Unfortunately the problem still remains. It is especially noticeable  when Chrome is running. I've tried several different versions of the Nvidia drivers (everything in the Additional Drivers tool). I'm currently running on version 352 from the xorg-edgers ppa with the same results. I have the same Ubuntu version running on a much slower laptop (Intel graphics) and everything is smooth. Is there any way to get better performance out of this card in Unity?

- Memory: 12 GiB
- Processor: Intel® Core™ i7-2600K CPU
- Graphics: GeForce GTX 750 Ti/PCIe/SSE2
- Monitor: Dell UltraSharp 27" 2560x1440 (connected with DisplayPort)

Comment: Does it appear to improve if you switch windows multiple times sequentially? I have the same problem on two machines with Nvidia cards, but I haven't been able to pin down the exact cause. However, the performance improves temporarily if I switch windows multiple times in a row. Then, after some time, it slows down again.

Comment: The only thing I had luck with was going into the Nvidia settings and changing the Powermizer setting to performance on boot. There's still a touch of lag but much better than before.

http://askubuntu.com/questions/419019/nvidia-settings-powermizer-performance-mode-on-12-04-4-64-bit